# Ubuntu SDK не запускается

Tags: qtcreator, ubuntusdk

QtCreator выдаёт ошибку при запуске:

> The current user can not access the LXD server which is required for the Ubuntu SDK.
>   Make sure the user is part of the lxd group and restart the IDE.

Как исправить??

Comment: а вам ясно что за ошибка? у вас с правами на запуск LXD проблема.

Comment: подобный вопрос освещался на другом ресурсе SO [тут](http://askubuntu.com/questions/835571/unable-to-run-ubuntu-sdk-cannot-access-lxd-server/836495)